# TopShelf Not Responding to Command Line Arguments

Tags: .net, topshelf

The TopShelf documentation says that [MyService.exe will respond to a range of command line arguments](http://docs.topshelf-project.com/en/latest/overview/commandline.html).  However, the documentation also shows absolutely [no indication that command-line parameters are being consumed by the main program](http://docs.topshelf-project.com/en/latest/overview/commandline.html).

Apparently this is working for everyone, because I've found no discussion of this problem anywhere.  And yes, unsurprisingly, when I try to execute `MyService.exe help` I get no response; it is not working for me.

I would expect the sample link above would at least contain the usual `args` formal parameter...

```
static void Main(string[] args) {...}
```

But it does not.  What am I missing?

### Update

I discovered the problem: the console application I had created in Visual Studio was somehow corrupt.  After deleting it and recreating it, the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internally TopShelf uses the BCL `Environment.CommandLine` property, which contains command line arguments, passed to your app. It's their design decision not to require command line arguments to be passed in explicitly.

For help problem you could try

```
HostFactory.Run(configurator =>
{
    configurator.AddCommandLineDefinition("yourCommand", f=> { /*some action*/});
    configurator.ApplyCommandLine();
```